# odbc_execute(): Not enough parameters... but there are

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

Using php odbc_prepare and odbc_execute I find it will often give me the following error:

> odbc_execute(): Not enough parameters (1 should be 2) given

And I'm positive I'm giving enough parameters, take this for example:

```
$sql = "
DECLARE @pk VARCHAR(50); 

SET @pk = (SELECT TOP(1) Col_name(ic.object_id, ic.column_id) AS ColumnName 
           FROM   sys.indexes AS i 
                  INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic 
                             INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c 
                                     ON ic.object_id = c.object_id 
                                        AND ic.column_id = c.column_id 
                          ON i.object_id = ic.object_id 
                             AND i.index_id = ic.index_id 
           WHERE  i.is_primary_key = 1 
                  AND ic.object_id = Object_id(?)); 

SELECT @pk AS pk;";

$params = ['customers'];
$statement = odbc_prepare($link,$sql);
odbc_execute($statement,$params);
```

Am I crazy? It's telling me I need 2 parameters but I built the query to only need one ?.

I found If I add an extra item to the parameters array of just null it will trick it into thinking it has the 2 it needs and execute properly.

Some notes:
We are using php 5.5.5, SQL Server 2012, and the ODBC driver Actual SQL Server

Comment: Sidenote: If `odbc_execute($statement,$params)` does have an ending semi-colon, great. If not, add one. `odbc_execute($statement,$params);`

Comment: I was gonna note that too but I figured he'd get a parse error instead

Comment: @Machavity True, I just wanted to let OP know; not the source of the problem.

Comment: @Rookie Have you, by any chance, tried the [sqlsrv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) extension? Might serve you better in the long run over ODBC

Comment: @Machavity We have looked into that. I don't remember the exact issue but something happened with it. We are on a mixed environment. Developing on Macs with Apache but deploying to a Windows IIS setup. It was a while ago, I found a bug in the free tds library that uses, did a patch, but was honestly lost when it came to compiling the project for Windows lol.